# Angular Controller error in index.ejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-material, mean-stack

I have an index.ejs page that has a slideMenu which inserts other HTML views in the index.ejs page.

Each html view has its own controller. Each controller is in its own .js file. I am including all these scripts in the index.ejs file, however this causes the following problem and the HTML views don't load properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
</head>

<body layout="column">
<!-- ANGULAR MATERIAL DEPENDENCIES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!-- ANGULAR MATERIAL DEPENDENCIES END-->


<md-content>
            <div ng-include="'/html/newCode/addCircleTimeSong.html'"></div>

</md-content>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

<script src="javascripts/newCode/Controller_CircleTimeSongPage.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/newCode/Controller_ObservationPage.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/newCode/Controller_CircleTimeActivityPage.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=CircleTimeSongPageController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have written this statement

```
var mainApp = angular.module("myapp", ['ngMaterial']);
```

in all the controller files. This is what causing this error. This statement creates and initializes the `myapp` module. So if you use this statement in all the controller files, you will be reinitializing the `myApp` every time hence the angular error.

Replace it with this statement in other controller files

```
var mainApp = angular.module("myapp");
```

The above statement means fetch/reference already created/initialized `myapp` module.